# Long running PHP process to serve API requests?

Tags: php, api, asynchronous

Apologies if this is too broad but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.

I want to have a single script run to listen to server sent events using an [EventSource client](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-eventsource-http-client) which is effectively a `while(true)` infinite loop to an external connection that remains open.

I want to store the data from the listener to local memory, let's simply say `$GLOBALS['data']`.

So

```
while($connection)
 $GLOBALS['data'] = $connection->stream()
```

Meanwhile, I want to expose an endpoint let's say `index.php/data` where if I make an API call to `GET /data`, it'll return the data in `$GLOBALS`

So two obvious hurdles here:

1. The `while(true)` loop that's streaming the data is blocking, but it seems I might be able to get around this with something like [async PHP](https://amphp.org/)
2. When an API call hits `index.php`, it spins up a separate PHP process and executes which isn't going to be sharing the same memory anyway and thus `$GLOBALS['data']` will be empty - so conceptually it's just an entirely separated process (correct?)

Is it possible to basically have an infinitely running script where a specific `while()` loop is running in the background storing to a local `$var`, and an API call can access the memory built by that script by returning `$var`?

I know this is a wonky question and there are myriad solutions like memcached/redis/databases etc., but I'm wondering if this is even possible or if there is fundamental missing piece here.

Comment: Generally with this kind of thing you'd have a PHP script face the web through a web server service (apache, nginx, iis, etc). Then when you need to run some larger complicated task, such as communicating with 3rd party apis which might fail, you'd want to have your web facing script put the "order" into a queue (This could be mysql, redis, amazon sqs, etc....)  so it's able to hand it off to a dedicated worker script. Then you'd have a long-running process (or multiple worker processes) which doesn't face the web, but check on the queue and run jobs etc. Until the job is finished.

Comment: Laravel is a very popular PHP framework, and people which use it generally reach for queues: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: Right, without constrains I'd just basically have a long-running script constantly storing data in database and then the API I build pull from that database. I'm just wondering if, conceptually, PHP can run a constant stream listener AND serve API requests all in a single, persistent process using the same locally shared memory

Comment: Many people choose node.js for this type of thing. While PHP and Node are both single-threaded, JavaScript has an event loop while PHP doesn't quite have one built-in but can emulate the behavior with enough dedication for async operations. By using async operations, you can listen to more incoming connections. But then you have to make sure everything you do in the script when you write your code is done in an async manner. Might check out stuff like reactphp, swoole, amp php, etc. These give you an event loop so you can write code in an async manner using an event loop etc.

Comment: @ShaneOH the answer you are looking for is yes, with both amphp and reactphp you can do that.

Comment: An infinite loop generally will reach 100% cpu. But the idea is with a library or framework which is designed for this kind of purpose, it can choose whether to sleep, usleep or not etc or to find some extra work it needs to do etc. Things like HTTP Requests it can do in an Async manner then it's all about finding stuff to do in the meantime or sleeping until the next iteration to avoid 100% cpu. This can be extremely difficult code to write from scratch. Best use something out there designed for async as they'd be built on top of an implementation of an event loop.

Comment: "spins up a separate PHP process". It's technically possible to do things like that using `pcntl_fork`, `parallel`, along with many other approaches etc. It can be very difficult to write that kind of stuff from scratch and manage it well for all the various situations. Fortunately you can just reach for something easier to use such as: https://amphp.org/parallel/processes